# OCaml - append all elements of a list to all elements of another list

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

Given string lists [a, b, c] and [d, e] for example,

return the list [ad, bd, cd, ae, be, ce].

Please don't give me an answer, just a point the the right direction for a new learner.

Comment: Please, read this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and try to change the way you ask questions. You don't provide the slightest effort to show us that you even thought about the problem.

Comment: You'd like to compute the cartesian product of 2 lists, then map each pair of elements to something else.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is tricky because you need to traverse two lists. If you write it as one function there are two recursions to keep track of.

One way to approach it is to start with a simpler problem. Say you have a list of strings `l` and a string `s`. Can you write a function that makes a new list with `s` appended to each of the strings in `l`?

There is a straightforward solution to this simpler problem using `List.map`. Or you can write an explicitly recursive function.

After that you have only one remaining recursion to figure out, which may be easier.

**Update**

Now you have your function you can easily write a function that appends a string to all the elements of the first list of strings. The layout would look like this:

```
let cross_concat list1 list2 =
   let concat_string_to_list1 s = concat_string_to_list list1 s in
   ...
```

With this definition, you can use `List.map` again to get the final results (need to concatenate the resulting lists of strings into one list). Or you can use `List.fold_right` to build up the result as you go. Or you can write your own recursive function.

If you haven't written too many recursive functions, this would be something to think through.

Comment: Thanks. I've created a function for the first part (appending a string to each element of a list):

`let concat_string_to_list lst str =
  List.map (fun x -> x ^ str) lst`

However I'll be honest I'm stumped on how to go the next level deeper and append every element in that list to every of the other